# Get Mac OS Sierra for VirtualBox

Tags: osx, virtualbox

I am doing an assignment for University and I need to install Mac OS Sierra. I have been looking for installing it, but all places I found are not official. 
So, do you know how can I achieve a .iso for Mac OS Sierra officially?
My professor says something about that the kernel is free distributed, but the GUI doesn't. It is for installing in VirtualBox.

Comment: @Christopher yes I want to do it legally, with virtualbox, but I haven got a macintosh.

Comment: The Mac OS X license doesn't permit it to be installed on non-Apple hardware. The kernel and various libraries and frameworks are [open-source](https://opensource.apple.com/release/os-x-10116/), but I'm not aware of any "distribution" that includes them all in installable form.

Comment: So, I don't understand why the professor says about installing this..

Comment: This is one of those "Don't ask strangers; ask your professor" sort of things. If your professor says you should be able to do something for an assignment, ask him or her how. Having a professor answer your reasonable questions about coursework is part of what you are paying tuition for.

Comment: @chepner IMHO, "it's not permitted" seems a reasonable-enough answer to me for this question; what do you think of making an Answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [macOS Sierra license](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/macOS1012.pdf):

> ... you are granted a limited, non-exclusive license to install, use and run one (1) copy of the Apple Software on a single **Apple-branded computer** at any one time.

As I mentioned in a comment, various *parts* of the operating system are open-source and [available for download](https://opensource.apple.com/release/os-x-10116/).